# Как не показывать предупреждение https протокола (Your connection is not private) в браузере?

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ssl, https, браузер

Есть  https протокол  сайт,  google chrome  объявляет  предупреждение (Your connection is not private).

Использую cross origin ajax  запрос к этому сайту, но ошибка и за ssl сертификата и скрипт после закрытия сессии не работает (до этого вручную переходил к сайту и ajax работал в течении сессии браузера)?

Есть ли возможность, для данного домена, навсегда пропустить это предупреждение  (или для всех доменов, если нету)?

Это не публичный под домен на моем сервере  используется для получения данных и вопросов безопасности нету .

Comment: Нет такой возможности. Если бы была - не было бы безопасности. Если "для себя" - сохраните сертификат себе в хранилище операционной системы. Если это публичный домен, получите его бесплатно у Let's Encrypt

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у вас есть сайт с валидным сертификатом. Вы заходите на свой сайт по https, а потом делаете ajax запрос на сторонний домен по протоколу http?

Comment: Нет это только для меня .
Сертификат не  валидный  (это под домен  на моем сервере) используется только для получения данных путем ajax запроса  (домен не публичный используется в админ панели)  имеют доступ только несколько человек и нужно чтобы в их браузере все работало  без  предупреждений безопасности

Comment: @Total Pusher  как сохранить сертификат в хранилище операционной системы (если есть силки буду рад посмотреть) ?

Comment: Как-то так https://www.nullalo.com/en/chrome-how-to-install-self-signed-ssl-certificates/